# Dependency issue in poetry install but working with pip

Tags: python, python-poetry

This is pyproject.toml is am using

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "xxx"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "xxx"
authors = ["xxx <xxx@xx.x>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10.13"
pypdf = "^4.0.1"
langchain = "^0.1.0"
langchain-community = "^0.0.11"
langchain-core = "^0.1.9"
chromadb = "0.3.29"
ipdb = "^0.13.13"
langchain-openai = "^0.0.5"
tqdm = "^4.66.1"
streamlit = "^1.31.0"
pymupdf = "^1.23.21"
opencv-python = "^4.9.0.80"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
jupyterlab = "^4.0.12"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I am doing `poetry install`, I am getting the following error, but previously this file was working fine.

```
• Installing duckdb (0.10.0): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for duckdb (0.10.0)

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:73 in choose_for
       69│ 
       70│             links.append(link)
       71│ 
       72│         if not links:
    →  73│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
       74│ 
       75│         # Get the best link
       76│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
       77│ 

Cannot install duckdb.
```

Now, when I activate the partially complete virtual env and do the `pip install duckdb`, it works , and after that, if I run `poetry install`, it runs successfully and `poetry.lock` file is formed.

Comment: Maybe duckdb is an optional dependency of one of the packages you include in pyproject.toml. What happens if you add duckdb 0.10.0 as a dependency in pyproject.toml?